# How to use a button to control multiple dices?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dice

I am writing a turn-based game with dices. When some hero has more than 1 dice, I add a button which can trigger multiple dices in a time.

The code I wrote has a bunch of errors. Where my logic is incorrect?

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class roolButton : MonoBehaviour
{

    //public static GameObject regularDice1, regularDice2, regularDice3, regularDice4;
    //public static GameObject specialDice1, specialDice2;
    regularDices regularDice1 = new regularDices();
    regularDices regularDice2 = new regularDices();
    regularDices regularDice3 = new regularDices();
    regularDices regularDice4 = new regularDices();
    specialDices specialDice1 = new specialDices();
    specialDices specialDice2 = new specialDices();
    //static GameObject regularDice1 = GameObject.Find("rd1");
    //static GameObject regularDice2 = GameObject.Find("rd2");
    //static GameObject regularDice3 = GameObject.Find("rd3");
    //static GameObject regularDice4 = GameObject.Find("rd4");
    //static GameObject specialDice1 = GameObject.Find("sd1");
    //static GameObject specialDice2 = GameObject.Find("sd2");
    public static bool hasSpecial;
    public static int numRegularDices;
    public static int numSpecialDices;
    //store dice objects in arraylsit
    ArrayList rdList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList sdList = new ArrayList();

    void start()
    {

        //regularDice1 = GameObject.Find("rd1");
        if (regularDice1 != null)
        {
            regularDice1.GetComponent<regularDices>();
        }

        //regularDice2 = GameObject.Find("rd2");
        if (regularDice2 != null)
        {
            regularDice2.GetComponent<regularDices>();
        }

        //regularDice3 = GameObject.Find("rd3");
        if (regularDice3 != null)
        {
            regularDice3.GetComponent<regularDices>();
        }

        //regularDice4 = GameObject.Find("rd4");
        if (regularDice4 != null)
        {
            regularDice4.GetComponent<regularDices>();
        }

        //specialDice1 = GameObject.Find("sd1");
        if (specialDice1 != null)
        {
            specialDice1.GetComponent<regularDices>();
        }

        //specialDice2 = GameObject.Find("sd2");
        if (specialDice2 != null)
        {
            specialDice2.GetComponent<regularDices>();
        }


    }


    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        StartCoroutine("activatedAllDices");
    }

    public static int activatedAllDices()
    {

        ArrayList List = new ArrayList();
        switch (numRegularDices)
        {

            case 1:
                regularDice1.RollTheDice();
                
                List.add(regularDice1);
                int max = getMaxResults(List);
                if (hasSpecial)
                {
                    int smax = actSpecialDice();
                    if (max > smax)
                    {
                        return max;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return smax;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    return max;
                }


            case 2:
                regularDice1.RollTheDice();
                regularDice2.RollTheDice();
                
                List.add(regularDice1);
                List.add(regularDice2);
                int max = getMaxResults(List);
                if (hasSpecial)
                {
                    actSpecialDice();
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            case 3:
                regularDice1.RollTheDice();
                regularDice2.RollTheDice();
                regularDice3.RollTheDice();
                
                List.add(regularDice1);
                List.add(regularDice2);
                List.add(regularDice3);
                int max = getMaxResults(List);
                if (hasSpecial)
                {
                    int smax = actSpecialDice();
                    if (max > smax)
                    {
                        return max;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return smax;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    return max;
                }
            case 4:
                regularDice1.RollTheDice();
                regularDice2.RollTheDice();
                regularDice3.RollTheDice();
                regularDice4.RollTheDice();
                
                List.add(regularDice1);
                List.add(regularDice2);
                List.add(regularDice3);
                List.add(regularDice4);
                int max = getMaxResults(List);
                if (hasSpecial)
                {
                    int smax = actSpecialDice();
                    if (max > smax)
                    {
                        return max;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return smax;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    return max;
                }
        }
    }

    public int actSpecialDice()
    {
        switch (numSpecialDices)
        {
            case 1:
                specialDice1.RollTheDice();
                return specialDice1.getFinalSide();
                break;

            case 2:
                specialDice1.RollTheDice();
                specialDice2.RollTheDice();
                ArrayList sList = new ArrayList();
                sList.add(specialDice1);
                sList.add(specialDice2);
                int smax = getMaxResults(sList);
                return smax;
                break;
        }
    }

    public static int getMaxResults(ArrayList nList)
    {
        int maxValue = 0;
        int[] diceValues;
        foreach (int dice in nList)
        {
            if (dice.getFinalSide() > maxValue)
            {
                maxValue = dice.getFinalSide();
            }

        }
        return maxValue;
    }

}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class regularDices : MonoBehaviour {

    // Array of dice sides sprites to load from Resources folder
    private static Sprite[] diceSides;

    // Reference to sprite renderer to change sprites
    private static SpriteRenderer rend;
    //
    public static int finalSide;
    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start () {

        // Assign Renderer component
        rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        // Load dice sides sprites to array from DiceSides subfolder of Resources folder
        diceSides = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Dices/regularDices/");
        Debug.Log(diceSides.Length);
    }
    
    // If you left click over the dice then RollTheDice coroutine is started
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        StartCoroutine("RollTheDice");
    }

    // Coroutine that rolls the dice
    private static IEnumerator RollTheDice()
    {

        // Variable to contain random dice side number.
        // It needs to be assigned. Let it be 0 initially
        int randomDiceSide = 0;

        // Final side or value that dice reads in the end of coroutine
        finalSide = 0;

        // Loop to switch dice sides ramdomly
        // before final side appears. 20 iterations here.
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            // Pick up random value from 0 to 5 (All inclusive)
            randomDiceSide = Random.Range(0, 5);

            // Set sprite to upper face of dice from array according to random value
            
            rend.sprite = diceSides[randomDiceSide];

            // Pause before next iteration
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        }

        // Assigning final side so you can use this value later in your game
        // for player movement for example
        finalSide = randomDiceSide + 1;

        // Show final dice value in Console
        Debug.Log(finalSide);
    }
    public int getFinalSide()
    {
        return finalSide;
    }

}
```

The another class special dice is the the same as the regular dice just with different number.
the main errors :

> *Assets\Scripts\Dice\rollButton.cs(83,17): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
> 'roolButton.regularDice1*
>
> *Assets\Scripts\Dice\rollButton.cs(85,22): error CS1061: 'ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'add' and no accessible extension
> method 'add' accepting a first argument of type 'ArrayList' could be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*
>
> *Assets\Scripts\Dice\rollButton.cs(111,22): error CS1061: 'ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'add' and no accessible extension
> method 'add' accepting a first argument of type 'ArrayList' could be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*
>
> *Assets\Scripts\Dice\rollButton.cs(157,22): error CS1061: 'ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'add' and no accessible extension
> method 'add' accepting a first argument of type 'ArrayList' could be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*
>
> *Assets\Scripts\Dice\rollButton.cs(107,13): error CS0163: Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case 2:') to another
> *

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]. It is also not an appropriate use for [tag:visual-studio]

Comment: Google each of those error messages separately.